# EHIC eligibility for dual national (British/German)

Tags: dual-citizenship, german-citizens, ehic

I receive a UK State Pension. I have dual nationality (British/German)and I live in Germany. Am I still entitled to an EHIC card (for use in Germany)  Thanks

Comment: I presume you are asking about getting an EHIC card from the UK rather than about getting one from Germany; is that correct?  Do you have a UK-issued S1 form, and have you registered it in Germany?  (See https://www.nhs.uk/using-the-nhs/healthcare-abroad/apply-for-a-free-ehic-european-health-insurance-card/.)  Also, you should be aware that UK-issued EHIC cards will probably be useless after March 30, 2019 or perhaps 2 years later.  (See https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-44850972.)

Comment: Yes that's right. I am presently awaiting delivery of the S1 form, and would like to be sure  an EHIC card would work for me as a dual German/British national. (I probably won't register the S1 here in Germany before the Brexit situation becomes clearer )

Answer (score 1):

The [official website](http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=563&langId=en) of the European Commission states that:

> To be eligible for a card, you must be insured by or covered by a state social security system in any Member State of the European Union, Iceland, Liechtenstein, Norway or Switzerland

***You are thus eligible*** because you're covered by the British state social security system. This is explained in [the FAQ under "What if I'm not working?"](http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=857&langId=en&intPageId=972):

> You receive cash benefits because of your activity as an employed or self-employed person. In this case, you will remain subject to the legislation of the country in which you were insured while working.

The EU social security coordination rules are generally applied based on residence, so your nationality does not matter here.

Comment: Thanks, folks The British EHIC lady asked me when I submitted my S1 details on the phone what my nationality was and I answered British. Then I remembered later that I have dual citizenship - I'm hoping this can't come back to me as having given false information and subsequently affect my claim.